# OData Routing with Optional Parameter

Tags: wcf, sharepoint, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I have an OData (v3) Web API 2 project that is a wrapper to another wcf web service. The intended client for this odata connection is SharePoint 2013. I am creating CRUD operations within this wrapper and noticed that when sharepoint is asked to delete something it send a request in this format: /Entity(Identity=XX) instead of it's normal /Entity(XX) that i have working normally. I need to be able to handle that request without breaking the other one. Here is my code:

```
    public IHttpActionResult GetSchool([FromODataUri] int key, ODataQueryOptions<School> queryOptions)
    {
        // validate the query.
        try
        {
            queryOptions.Validate(_validationSettings);
        }
        catch (ODataException ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
        SchoolDataSource data = new SchoolDataSource();
        var result = data.GetByID(key);
        return Ok<School>(result);
        //return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented);
    }
```

This works fine for a request for /Schools(1), but not for /Schools(ID=1). i have tried adding:
`[Route("Schools(ID={key}")]`
And this makes the /Schools(ID=1) route work, but breaks pretty much everything else (406 Errors). i tried adding the above attribute and
`[Route("Schools({key})")]`to see if i can get them both working, but it doesn't function correctly either. I am very new to this, and was hoping to at least get some direction. Here is my WebApiConfig:

```
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.EnableQuerySupport();
        config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;

        // Web API configuration and services
        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<School>("Schools");
        builder.DataServiceVersion = new Version("2.0");
        config.Routes.MapODataRoute("odata", null, builder.GetEdmModel());
        // Web API routes


        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Errors i get:
406 if i have the route attribute set. 500 if i dont have the route attribute set. it seems as though my service has no idea how to handle the parameter unless i specify it, but if i do, all calls get 406 errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may not be the best approach, but made it work with this class:

```
public class SharePointRoutingConvention : EntitySetRoutingConvention
{
    public override string SelectAction(ODataPath odataPath, HttpControllerContext context,
        ILookup<string, HttpActionDescriptor> actionMap)
    {
        //Gets the entity type
        IEdmEntityType entityType = odataPath.EdmType as IEdmEntityType;

        //makes sure the format is correct
        if (odataPath.PathTemplate == "~/entityset/key")
        {
            //parses out the path segment (Identity=X)
                            KeyValuePathSegment segment = odataPath.Segments[1] as KeyValuePathSegment;

            //Gets the verb from the request header
            string actionName = context.Request.Method.ToString();

            // Add keys to route data, so they will bind to action parameters.
            KeyValuePathSegment keyValueSegment = odataPath.Segments[1] as KeyValuePathSegment;

            //Checks to see if the "Identity=" part is in the url
            if (keyValueSegment.Value.Contains("Identity="))
            {
                //removes the extra text
                context.RouteData.Values[ODataRouteConstants.Key] = keyValueSegment.Value.Replace("Identity=", "");
            }
            else
            {
                //parses it normally
                context.RouteData.Values[ODataRouteConstants.Key] = keyValueSegment.Value;
            }

            //returns the verb
            return actionName;

        }
        // Not a match.
        return null;
    }
}
```

and make the change to the webapiconfig:

```
        var conventions = ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefault();

        //adding the custom odata routing convention
        conventions.Insert(0, new SharePointRoutingConvention());



     config.Routes.MapODataRoute(
            routeName: "odata",
            routePrefix: null,//this is so that you can type the base url and get metadata back (http://localhost/) 
            model: builder.GetEdmModel(),
            pathHandler: new DefaultODataPathHandler(),
            routingConventions: conventions //this assigns the conventions to the route
            );
```